# How to apply multiple filters in google analytics

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

How to filter multiple dimensions in Google analytics.

Nether of the following work:

```
 .setFilters("ga:userType==anonymous").setFilters( "ga:dimension3==1234")
 .setFilters("ga:userType==anonymous","ga:dimension3==1234")
```

The second one gives an error.

Answer (score 12):

You need to string them together.

> [Combining Filters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=en#filters) Filters can be combined using OR and AND boolean
>   logic. This allows you to effectively extend the 128 character limit
>   of a filter expression.

**The OR operator is defined using a comma (,).**

```
ga:country==United%20States,ga:country==Canada
```

**The AND operator is defined using a semi-colon (;).**

```
ga:country==United%20States;ga:browser==Firefox
```

I am not sure what language that is but its probably going to be more like

```
setFilters("ga:userType==anonymous,ga:dimension3==1234")
```

Comment: This works in query builder. Thanks! Query builder reference: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

.setFilters takes only one string 
.setFilters(String, String) gives an error.

Putting 2 lines 
.setFilters(String1)
.setFilters(String2) 
does not filter the data as desired.

As a work around, I created a segment and put all the filters there and used that segment in my data pull. so working for now but still looking for the filter code